# Can I expose the signup form through views 2?

Tags: 7, forms, views, users

I am using [Signup](http://drupal.org/project/signup) and [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) in Drupal 6 (I can't install Drupal 7), and I created a view that lists all the nodes for which users can signup.
Now I want to enable users to signup for one of these nodes without forcing them to navigate to the node itself, and I need to expose the signup form though Views (perhaps using a PHP field). I've searched for this, but most of the comments are a few years old. Furthermore, I'm rather unfamiliar with PHP.

Can I expose the signup form through views 2? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a feature request for the Signup module (originally submitted to that module's issue queue 3 days before this StackExchange post). For the latest progress on this feature, see the issue: http://drupal.org/node/1118448 .

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it can be done with [Views Embed Form](http://drupal.org/project/views_embed_form).

I couldn't get the form to display, due to permissions errors despite not having any access constraints (like [vermo](http://drupal.org/node/886520), although they somehow got it to work).
Documentation is at http://drupal.org/node/329511.

My basic module contains the follow function.

```
function MYMODULE_views_embed_form() {
  return array(
    'signup_form' => t('Signup form')
  );
}
```

Comment: Same problem, I manage to get the an error there, but have no clue how to solve the permissions error... Anyone?